# Regex for deserializing string separated by semi-colon

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that has the following format:-

`"{\"A5\";\"A6\";\"A7\";\"varying number of params...\"}"`

How can I use PHP to convert the string into
`A5, A6, A7, varying number of params...`

I know `str_replace` is a way, but I was wondering if it's something better done with regex?

Comment: Don't use regex for this. It's more complicated that a combination of `str_replace` and `explode`.

Comment: Can `;` appear inside quotes? The format you have suggests that it is possible.

Comment: Would be simpler if you hadn't encoded it twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=\\")[^\\;]+
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/53

```
$re = "/(?<=\\\\\")[^\\\\;]+/";
$str = "\"{\"A5\";\"A6\";\"A7\";\"varying number of params...\"}\"";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Details:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \\                       '\' 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\\;]+                  any character except: '\\', ';' (1 or more
                       times (matching the most amount possible))
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) with arrays if you don't need the power of regex:

```
echo str_replace(array('"{\"', '\";\"', '\"}"'), array("", ", ", ""), $str);
```

-> `A5, A6, A7, varying number of params...` [test at eval.in](https://eval.in/241598)

Comment: Thanks you like it @vks :) I see you have many points already! Grats 10k+